# Vertical Stack bars with percentages and values

Tags: tableau-desktop

- Using Tableau desktop 2022 version
- Want to know how and if possible to build the following:

**Columns** : FieldB (has only 6 possible values but could increase a little in the future)

**Rows** : FieldA (has 10 rows for now)

**Stacke bar Graphic** : would display on the right side next to each of the possible rows values (10). So for each row (10) a vertical graph with all the FieldB (6) values in percent and number.

- The FieldB values (the 6 ones) would be displayed as a selection option (radio button)
- The user could select 1 or up to 6 options (coming from FieldB) and the corresponging stack bar graphic will display percentage% values
- If the user selects only 1 option (coming from FieldB) then the stack bar graph displayed would be a normal stack bar graph
- If the user selects more than 1 option (coming from FieldB) then the stack bar graph displayed would be a percentage stack bar graph

Is this even possible ? Any tips/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: Hi and thanks for asling. I tried a couple of things including a way to display the FielB as vertically amd as a filter BUT no quite able to allow multiple radio button selections. I swithched to something different in the meantime.     --->QUESTION : Did you had something to suggest ?

Comment: It is possible to build what you are asking. Please add what you have tried as screenshots to your question so we may be able to better help answer your question. Also please read [this article on asking questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I simply forgot to close this post since it was opened 26 says ago and found out a wotkaround as mentionned above but i will try and put print screens on future posts if requested/needed without showing restricted data that is. Thank you all in this forum and this is something i tried : https://kb.tableau.com/articles/HowTo/how-to-create-horizontal-parameter-selection-with-radio-buttons